# J2ME ssl connection with self signed key

Tags: ssl, java-me, self-signed

I want to create connection to a server with https connection, I want to use self signed ssl key, but when open the connection with `Connector.open(url)` the following exception is eccured :

> javax.microedition.pki.CertificateException: Certificate was issued by an unrecognized entity
>
> com.sun.midp.pki.X509Certificate.verifyChain(), bci=6
>    - com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.parseChain(), bci=106
>    - com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.rcvCert(), bci=92
>    - com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.doHandShake(), bci=77
>    - com.sun.midp.ssl.SSLStreamConnection.(), bci=161
>    - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.https.Protocol.connect(), bci=215
>    - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(), bci=164
>    - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(), bci=7
>    - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=33
>    - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=3
>    - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.https.Protocol.getSecurityInfo(), bci=5
>    - main.MainMidlet.commandAction(MainMidlet.java:66)
>    - javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$ChameleonTunnel.callScreenListener(), bci=39
>    - com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.processCommand(), bci=62
>    - com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.soft1(), bci=27
>    - com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.keyInput(), bci=48
>    - com.sun.midp.chameleon.CWindow.keyInput(), bci=30
>    - javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayEventConsumerImpl.handleKeyEvent(), bci=43
>    - com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process(), bci=252
>    - com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run(), bci=130
>    - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=5

can any body help me with a sample code to solve problem.

Comment: you should import your server certificate to the WTK in the certificate management area. and make sure it has the same name IP address in CN area when you generate your certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The server's self-signed certificate isn't trusted by the client. Either get it signed by a CA or exported into the client's truststore.